# ASP.NET Core 3.0 get_HostingEnvironment() Method not found in extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

Below code to replicate error for some extensions I'm trying to create in a new ASP.NET Core 3.0 API project.

```cs
using ClassLibrary1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

              webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
              {
                // this works fine
                var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
              });

              webBuilder.CustomConfigureAppConfiguration();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
              // this works fine
              var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            })
            .CustomConfigureAppConfiguration();
  }
}
```

This `Extensions` class needs to be in a different project. Seems to work fine when in same main project.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

// This project can be either netstandard2.0 or netcoreapp3.0
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static IWebHostBuilder CustomConfigureAppConfiguration(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
      hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
      {
        // this fails with System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderContext.get_HostingEnvironment()'.'
        var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
      });

      return hostBuilder;
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CustomConfigureAppConfiguration(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
      hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
      {
        // this fails with System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilderContext.get_HostingEnvironment()'.'
        var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
      });

      return hostBuilder;
    }
  }
}
```

It only fails at runtime, and only when accessing the `HostingEnvironment`. When removing/commenting the `var env = context.HostingEnvironment;` assignment, I can still inspect & view it fine in debug.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

**EDIT**

Updating the `ClassLibrary1` project to `netcoreapp3.0` and adding `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` like below works:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'd still like to keep the project as `netstandard2.0` if possible. Perhaps some specific NuGet package I need for that?

Comment: check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-the-project-file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the `netstandard2.0` project, I could only get the `HostingEnvironment` in the `HostBuilderContext` (from `IHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`) - with the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` package installed:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CustomConfigureAppConfiguration(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
  hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
  {
    // this works with Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions installed
    var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
  });

  return hostBuilder;
}
```

`HostingEnvironment` from `WebHostBuilderContext` (from IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration) still throws an exception when executed by a `netcoreapp3.0` project. This worked fine with previous versions.

Also I can still inspect it during debug when commented out:
[image]

Something still seems a bit off, but at least this works now.

**UPDATE**

After more digging I found the difference in references:
-  `netcoreapp3.0` - via *shared framework* `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0`
- `netstandard2.0` via NuGet `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0`

v2.2 exposes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment` which has been [deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/344) in v3.0

As of 2019/10/01 v3.0 is not available on NuGet.

Comment: As you have found, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` are in different locations between `netcoreapp3.0` and `netstandard2.0`. From `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp3.0`, there are many break changes, you may keep targeting to `netcoreapp3.0` with the workaround in your origianl post. For `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` with version 3.0, its target is `netcoreapp3.0` which means, you could not use it in `netstandard2.0`.

Comment: 100% @TaoZhou - the only confusing thing is still why I can inspect the value during debug. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Worked for me with .NET Core 3.1/.NET Standard 2.1. Added `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />` into shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your `HostingEnvironment` with `WebHostEnvironment`.

As the document says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure

> Replace IHostingEnvironment with IWebHostEnvironment and add a using statement for the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting namespace.

Comment: It's not available on either `HostBuilderContext` (from `IHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`) or `WebHostBuilderContext` (from `IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case (EF 3.0) I was using one project with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting (3.0.1)`. This was using a class from a different project. This second project included `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (3.0.5)`. This package has `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (3.0.14)` as a dependency. This includes `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting (2.1.0)`, which was incompatible with EF 3.0. Including

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.1" />
```

in the second project solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as well; As you noted, It seems the bottom line is simply that it's not going to work as ASP.NET 3.x is only supported on `netcoreapp3.x` projects.

Like you, Once i converted my `netstandard2.0` library to `netcoreapp3.0` (or .1 at this point really) and pulled in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework reference (rather than pulling the entire `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web`) it sorted itself out.

Not the greatest answer, but its a "known"/by-design decision to simply leave netstandard2.0/netframework behind.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my serverless API had another project as a reference. On that referenced project I was using the following PackageReference:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

I was able to put this to work only after changing the version to 2.1.0
I was using versions v3+

Please check this [thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/710).